# Would using Redux on Angular without ng2-redux be a bad practice?

Tags: angular

I ask because the ng2-redux adds a layer of complexity, async pipes and a bunch of setup, when all we really need to do to use redux natively is subscribe/unsubscribe to the store on any component/service that uses it - letting change detection handle DOM updates - like so:

```
 sub
 store = store.getStore()

 ngOnDestroy(){
     sub()
 }

 ngOnInit(){
     sub = store.subscribe(d => this.store = d)
 }
```

Is it a bad practice to use redux natively?

Why would you opt to use the library?

Comment: why would you prefer to manually subscribe/unsubscribe instead of (ab)using the async pipe?

Comment: Personally I tried angular-redux/store, mobx and ngrx and prefer angular-redux/store because it's less opinionated. I would go for the no-library option for reasons you stated, but would have to know Redux pattern really well to not get into trouble.

Comment: I'm still quite new the ecosystem, so forgive me if i'm wrong, but it seems more direct - making it feel simpler. Your state is accessible directly within the component through the `store` variable

Comment: I ended up creating a decorator `@Store(reduxStore) public localvarname` which, behind the scenes, subscribes/unsubscribes to the store oninit/ondestroy of the component, providing a simplified interface for the components to use.

Answer (score 0):

We are using redux with seamless-immutable package and writing our "actions" and "reducers".

Here is the package.json part

```
"redux": "^3.6.0",
"redux-seamless-immutable": "^0.3.0"
```

There are two popular redux implementations for Angular.

ngrx: Reactive Extensions for Angular
angular.redux: Angular 2+ bindings for Redux

It cannot be said which is better. Angular-redux uses the existing implementation of React. ngrs ist a own implementation on the basis of RxJS. In principle, it is recommended to study both projects.

Don't miss the Redux extension for Chrome!